# US-citizens unemployment-benefits Virginia while visiting aboard

Tags: us-citizens, unemployment-benefits

- I am a US citizen who has been on Qatar since January 2018 on Visitor Visa till today July/7/2020.
- I was staying in Qatar to visit family and complete an online master program.
- During this time I was self-employed selling Microsoft licenses here in Qatar.
- I did file taxes for 2018 and 2019 as a self-employed.
- I do hold a Virginia driver license which I did renew on 2019 (online).
- Am I eligible for Virginia unemployment insurance or Pandemic Unemployment Assistance (PUA)?

Comment: Today is (was, in most of the world) June 7, not July 7.